# Rails acts_as_taggable - tagged_with through a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

Lets say I have a User / Post model like the example here:

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-cloud-calculations

User has many Posts and Posts belong to User.  Posts have tags.  Can I easily search for Users that have a particular tagged post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically have:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  acts_as_taggable

  # under the hood, this declaration creates
  # following relations
  has_many :tags
  has_many :taggings
end
```

You can now add the following relation to `User`:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :tags, through: :posts
  # has_many :taggings, through: :posts
end
```

Now querying for a given `@tag` should be easy:

```
users_with_give_tag = User.joins(:tags).where("tags.id=?", @tag.id)
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."taggable_id" = "posts"."id" AND "taggings"."context" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ?
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id"
WHERE (tags.id=1)  [["context", "tags"], ["taggable_type", "Post"]]
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I had issue because on my first iteration I had acts_as_taggable in my User model to start and that caused the results to be nil.

Comment: how would you extend the search for multiple tags ? Like , find users whose posts are tagged with tags "a"  and "b"